# BIRT report error column binding

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I have a BIRT report which worked fine up until I altered the database it connected to. I deleted a column out of a table on the database and removed any call to it in my data query and now I'm getting this error whenever I try and generate a BIRT report.

```
The following items have errors: 

Data (id = 291): 
+ Column binding "isComplete_18" has referred to a data set column "isComplete_18" which does not exist. (Element ID:291) 

Data (id = 298): 
+ Column binding "isComplete_18" has referred to a data set column "isComplete_18" which does not exist. (Element ID:298) 

Data (id = 292): 
+ Column binding "isComplete_18" has referred to a data set column "isComplete_18" which does not exist. (Element ID:292) 

Data (id = 299): 
+ Column binding "isComplete_18" has referred to a data set column "isComplete_18" which does not exist. (Element ID:299) 

Data (id = 293): 
+ Column binding "isComplete_18" has referred to a data set column "isComplete_18" which does not exist. (Element ID:293) 

Data (id = 300): 
+ Column binding "isComplete_18" has referred to a data set column "isComplete_18" which does not exist. (Element ID:300) 

Data (id = 585): 
+ Column binding "isComplete_18" has referred to a data set column "isComplete_18" which does not exist. (Element ID:585) 

Table (id = 443): 
+ Column binding "name_19" has referred to a data set column "name_19" which does not exist. (Element ID:443) 

Data (id = 583): 
+ Column binding "isComplete_18" has referred to a data set column "isComplete_18" which does not exist. (Element ID:583)
```

A google search isn't turning up much other then unresolved issues, and I'm not sure how to proceed. I've tested out the query in phpmyadmin, and it returns the expected results, yet in BIRT I get nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Both of the answers below are potential fixes. Deleting things in BIRT can leave ghosts that cause problems.  You either have to find the ghost and remove it, or you have to build a fresh report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely you have a reference of the deleted column in the report XML file, go to the XML view and search for : "isComplete_18", "name_19", and delete each xml element containing that string.

After manually removing every reference to the two columns, rerun the report again ...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem once. It seems (don't know exactly) that the report is binding columns that doesn't exist anymore when you change the database or change some things on the DataSet (for me it was the second case).

I tried this and worked for me:

- Select your table;
- Go to "Property Editor";
- Go to "Binding" tab;
- Click "Clear";
- Select the same Data Set you are using before;
- Try to generate the report.

Hope that it could help you!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the property editor for the table. Then the binding tab. There is a binding in there under Data Column Binding that still is linked to the old column you were referencing.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was, searched in the XML source for the element and deleted it there.

Answer (score -1):

After making changes to your report in BIRT, you should go to the XML file of your report and remove the "isComplete_18" element. This will resolve the issue and ensure that the report functions properly.

[image]